# Get a list of the 1-element swap from an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, swap

From a given array I need a list of all the *1-element-swap* list. I dont know how is this called so better if I explain it with an example.

For example. For a given `array` :

`array = [1,2,3,4]`

I need the output:

```
[2,1,3,4]
[3,2,1,4]
[4,2,3,1]
[1,3,2,4]
[1,4,3,2]
[1,2,4,3]
```

This means if `K` is the size of the array, I must get a `(K(K-1))/2` output arrays.

In the example above, `K=4` so `4(3)/2=6` output arrays.

I really dont know how to do it. I know there's the `itertools` function, but if I use `itertools.permutations(array)` I don't get my desired solution as this shows me all the permutations, and I only need a list of the "1 swap element" list.

Comment: Have you tried simply looping through the values and swapping each of them with all other values? And then removing doubles obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> for i in xrange(len(x)):
...     for j in xrange(i + 1, len(x)):
...         y = x[:]
...         y[i], y[j] = y[j], y[i]
...         print y
...
```

Comment: If you are using python 3 replace `xrange` with `range`, and `print y` with `print(y)`;

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

# swaps to elements, and return the resulting array
def swap(x, i, j):
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    return x

arrays = [swap(array[:], i, j) 
                 for i in range(len(array))
                 for j in range(i + 1, len(array))]

print(arrays)
```